# How to implement a parallel processing with **direct** endpoint in Camel?

Tags: java, parallel-processing, apache-camel

Below testing code doesn't work

```
from("direct:start").setExchangePattern(ExchangePattern.InOnly).threads(5).delay(2000).bean(MessageHeaderValidator.class);
```

Although **seda** is the alternative, referring to [Camel seda document](http://camel.apache.org/seda.html). It is recommended to use the **direct** endpoint instead.

**Thread pools**

Be aware that adding a thread pool to a SEDA endpoint by doing something like:

```
from("seda:stageName").thread(5).process(...)
```

Can wind up with two BlockQueues: one from the SEDA endpoint, and one from the workqueue of the thread pool, which may not be what you want.Instead, you might wish to configure a Direct endpoint with a thread pool, which can process messages both synchronously and asynchronously. For example:

```
from("direct:stageName").thread(5).process(...)
```

You can also directly configure number of threads that process messages on a SEDA endpoint
using the concurrentConsumers option.

Comment: What didn't work? Who says that using the seda component is not recommended?

Comment: The code doesn't executed in parallel as mentioned in Camel document.

The recommendation is documented here
http://camel.apache.org/seda.html

Comment: You shouldn't us a the SEDA endpoint together with a thread pool. But using one or the other is ok.

Answer (score 1):

For parallel processing, use Camel's SEDA component with the `concurrentConsumers` option:

```
from("seda:stageName?concurrentConsumers=5")
    .process(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

The root cause is, the message is passing in one by one in a for loop with a producerTemplate which is blocking.

Comment: i suggest you delete your question, since it turned out to be something else than what is asked